# MIDI. Срабатывает catch вместо try

Tags: java

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class MiniMiniMusicApp {
    public void play(){
        try{
            Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            player.open();
            Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ,4);
            Track track = seq.createTrack();

            ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
            a.setMessage(144,1,44,100);
            MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(a,1);
            track.add(noteOn);

            ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
            a.setMessage(128,1,44,100);
            MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(a,1);
            track.add(noteOff);

            player.setSequence(seq);
            player.start();

        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
     /**
      * @param args the command line arguments
      */
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        MiniMiniMusicApp mini = new MiniMiniMusicApp();
        mini.play();
     }

}
```

Только неделю как начал изучать Java и в книге HeadFirst Java(изучаем java) вот такой пример, возможно вы подскажете как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте вывод ввидет текста, а не картинки

Comment: Вот же - аналогичный вопрос [ССЫЛКА](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614740/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-5-%D1%81-software-javasoft-prefs)